# dynamic menu using jQuery. Menu details should be read using XML file

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "jQueryTest.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find('Title').each(function () {
                    var subTitle = $(this).find('SubTitle').text();
                    $(this).append('<li>' + subTitle);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: do you want to add the elements to the clicked li?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jxnz17cc/

Comment: `$(document).('click','li',function () {` try this is newly added `li` s don't function as needed.

Comment: i want to create dynamic menu using xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much wrong with the provided [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxnz17cc/16/). I've gotten it to work:

[image: demo]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var $li = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // GET - post required on jsfiddle
            url: "/echo/xml/", // url - path/to/jQueryTest.xml
            dataType: "xml",
            data: { // disregard - just for echo server
                    xml: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Title>foo<SubTitle>bar</SubTitle></Title>', 
                    delay: 3
            },            
            success: function (xml) {
                console.log(xml);
                $(xml).find('Title').each(function (i, el) {
                    var subTitle = $(el).find('SubTitle').text();
                    $li.after('<li>' + subTitle+'</li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

## EDIT

[image]

For that, try something like below. Here's a new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnsa92qr/14/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var $li = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // GET - post required on jsfiddle
            url: "/echo/xml/", // url - path/to/jQueryTest.xml
            dataType: "xml",
            data: { // disregard - just for echo server
                    xml: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Title>foo<SubTitle>bar</SubTitle></Title>',
                    delay: 3
            },            
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find('Title').each(function (i, el) {
                    var $subtitle = $('<span />', {
                        text: $(el).find('SubTitle').text()
                    }),
                    $title = $('<li>', {
                        html: el.childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                        on: {
                            mouseenter: function(e) {
                                $(this).find('span').show();
                            },
                            mouseleave: function(e) {
                                $(this).find('span').hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }).append($subtitle.hide());

                    $li.after($title);
                });
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: but it give all title and subtitle from the xml file at a time.i want to show the subtitle only on mouseover of the list which is created by dyanamic